# application navigation drawer not running on api higher than 22

Tags: java, android, api, navigation

the application runs perfectly on androids with api 22 but it crashes when I use higher version.

I created a new navigation drawer and is perfectly fine and still running on higher api until I add the code. The code is purposed to get data from database and add it to menu as item dynamically.

the code runs fine when i use android with api 19 - 22 but crashes on higher versions. how can I fix this ?

this is the code I added

```
private void addMenuItemInNavMenuDrawer() {
    NavigationView navView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    Menu menu = navView.getMenu();
    Menu submenu = menu.addSubMenu("");
    Result = tutClass.loadAllData();
    if (Result.equals("Success")){
        tutID = tutClass.getId();
        title = tutClass.getTitle();

        for (int a = 0; a< title.length;a++){
            final int b = a + 1;
            submenu.add(a + 1, Integer.valueOf(tutID[a]) + 1 , Menu.NONE, title[a])
            .setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    setItemOnClickItem(b);
                    return false;
                }
            });

        }

    }
    else {
        showMessage(Result);
    }

    navView.invalidate();
}
```

//===============================================================================================================================

```
private void setItemOnClickItem(int id){

    try{
        llLayout.removeAllViews();
        Result = tutClass.searchData(id);
        if (Result.equals("Success")){
            code = tutClass.getCode();
            title = tutClass.getTitle();
            topic = tutClass.getTopic();

            TextView title1 = new TextView(TutwithNavigation.this);
            title1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            title1.setText(String.valueOf(title[0]));
            title1.setAllCaps(true);
            title1.setTextSize(50);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                title1.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
            }
            title1.setBackgroundColor(000);
            llLayout.addView(title1);


            if (code.length != 0){
                code = code[0].split("\\`");
            }
            if (topic.length != 0){
                topic = topic[0].split("\\`");
            }

            if ((code.length == 0) && (topic.length != 0)){

                for (int a = 0; a < topic.length;a++){

                    TextView topic1 = new TextView(TutwithNavigation.this);
                    topic1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    topic1.setText(String.valueOf(topic[a]));
                    topic1.setBackgroundColor(0001);
                    topic1.setTextSize(30);
                    llLayout.addView(topic1);


                }
            }
            else if ((topic.length == 0) && (code.length != 0)){

                for (int a = 0; a < code.length;a++){

                    TextView code1 = new TextView(TutwithNavigation.this);
                    code1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    code1.setText(String.valueOf(code[a]));
                    code1.setTextSize(30);
                    code1.setBackgroundColor(1);
                    llLayout.addView(code1);


                }
            }
            else{

                for (int a = 0; a < code.length;a++){

                    TextView topic1 = new TextView(TutwithNavigation.this);
                    topic1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    topic1.setText(String.valueOf(topic[a]));
                    topic1.setBackgroundColor(0001);
                    topic1.setTextSize(30);
                    llLayout.addView(topic1);

                    TextView code1 = new TextView(TutwithNavigation.this);
                    code1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    code1.setText(String.valueOf(code[a]));
                    code1.setTextSize(30);
                    code1.setBackgroundColor(1);
                    llLayout.addView(code1);
                }

            }
        }
        else {
            showMessage(Result);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){ showMessage(e.toString());}
}
```

the goal of this code is to add TextView on the constraint layout when I click item on the menu in the navigation drawer.

this is the oncreate method

```
public void Start(){
    llLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tutLayout);

}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tutwith_navigation);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    Start();
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    addMenuItemInNavMenuDrawer(); // THE APPLICATION STARTS NOT RUNNING HERE. EVERYTHING STARTS WHEN I ADD THIS


}
```

Comment: Look at [the stack trace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173) to determine the cause of the crash.

Comment: thank you so much .. I found the error. I instantiated the SqliteDBclass without setting the contentview first which led to nullexception error in the context.